Boot and Suspend to Ram problems, Acer Aspire E 15, Ubuntu 24.04
I have a Acer laptop that is crashing after waking from sleep and fails to load Ubuntu after every second boot. After waking from sleep, it's as if the SSD got disconnected and the PC is solely running off the RAM, when you try to open anything it crashes and you have to hold the power button to shutdown and boot back up. On the first boot after a hard shutdown (holding down the power button) it loads Ubuntu fine, but if you shut down normally and try to boot, it stays on the Ubuntu splash loading screen forever until I hold down the power button, shut down and boot back up.
It's driving me insane trying to figure this out. The only lead I have is that every time to PC boots it creates a memory mapped unknown device in the efi boot manager.
Here's my efi:
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0000,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* HDD: kimtigo SSD 256GB    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x11,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,f3fdbc44-4844-46da-ad63-9188dcf0488c,0x800,0x219800)RC
Boot0001* Unknown Device:   MemoryMapped(11,0x985e8000,0x98d13fff)/FvFile(c57ad6b7-0515-40a8-9d21-551652854e37)5243a695de30
Boot0002* Unknown Device:   MemoryMapped(11,0x985e8000,0x98d13fff)/FvFile(c57ad6b7-0515-40a8-9d21-551652854e37)5243a695de30
Boot0004* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,f3fdbc44-4844-46da-ad63-9188dcf0488c,0x800,0x219800)/File(\EFI\LINUX\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

